# Using StreetViewPanorama for an Android panorama viewer app?

Tags: android, google-street-view, panoramas, 360-panorama-viewer

My application's output would be a panorama photo. I looked around for solutions but I couldn't find one which I liked. Almost all of what I saw were an exact copy of a many years old project back on code.google, using GL ES 10 only.

I'd like possible good performance and I also want to avoid reinventing the wheel. Google's Open Spherical API (https://developers.google.com/streetview/open-spherical-camera/) is great, but I need an implementation for a viewer.

I'm wondering if it's possible to reuse `StreetViewPanorama`'s capabilities to implement a 360 viewer leaving out the Google Maps portion. Looks like that `getStreetViewPanorama` requires a `MapView`. If not `StreetViewPanorama`, is there another API I could use?

Or is there some intent I can fire? In that case I should tell though that I periodically would like to update the displayed 360 image.

Comment: i dont think streetviewpanorama requires mapview please read the docs here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/streetview

Comment: @RashidCordero Maybe you are right, I gonna have to check it out.